# Український відповідник до слова "Соискатель"

Tags: відповідник, аналог

Який україніський відповідник до слова "Соискатель"?

Потрібен аналог англійського "Job seeker".

Comment: Це запитання сильно виграло б, якби воно містило **переклад своїми словами**. Також, запитання, які не демонструють **спроби автора самостійно відповісти** на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: "Соискатель" не точно відповідає словосполученню "Job seeker", а лише може замінювати в певному змісті. "Претендент для роботи" - можливо підійде у вашому випадку.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, або «претендент на певну посаду».

Answer (score 1):

Аналогом англійського буде - шукач роботи. Використовується словосполучення на сайті https://www.work.ua/articles/

Comment: А на [rabota.ua](https://rabota.ua/ua) використовують _пошукач_ (прогорнути сторінку донизу - розділ "пошукачеві"; також, наприклад, [тут](https://thepoint.rabota.ua/pomylky-poshukachiv-yaki-dratuyut-robotodavtsiv/)).

Comment: Щодо цього слова "шукач" є стаття-дослідження в інтернеті, в якій пояснюється російське походження цього слова і наводяться докази щодо того, що правильніше використовувати здобувач.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, посилання дасте?

Comment: http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/75569/90-Vlasenko.pdf?sequence=1 сторінка 4

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko в статті наче йдеться про слово *здобувач* в значенні людини, яка хоче отримати науковий ступінь, а тут говоримо про *job seeker*, тому ваш коментар хибний.

Comment: Так, це правда, не дочитав. Там трохи заплутано написано. Правильно шукач.